# CSS margin:auto unequal

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a menu bar centered. My code is:

```
.menu
{
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  
    position:relative;
    top: -25px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 900px;
   background-color: #BFBFBF;
   text-align: center;
}
```

The right & left sides are unequal. I'm at a complete loss as to why the menu has more room on the left than on the right. You can see the page here: http://www.ruthbavetta.com/sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the element `.menu` has a greater width than the container content box.
The container `.content` has a padding of `10px` around, and a width of `895px`.

```css
.content {
  width: 895px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

While the `.menu` has a width of `900px`.

```css
.menu {
    width: 900px;
}
```

You need to reduce the width of the menu if you want to get it to center. Or use a width of `100%` to fill the entire space of the container element.

Comment: @user3313706 Don't mention it :) Since you're new to SO, please consider accepting the answer which you've found it useful, by clicking on the check mark.